# Как использовать структуры c++ из dll-ки в с#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Есть dll написаная на с++. Необходмо испльзовать ее в с#.
heder c++

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef CRZUSBH
#define CRZUSBH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef CRZUSB_EXPORTS
#define CRZUSB_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CRZUSB_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define SIZE_MATR_ADDR_RECV         512
#define MAX_COUNT_RZ_DATA               128
#define MAX_COUNT_CHANNELS          16

#define FREQ_RZ_GET_DEVICE          0x00
#define FREQ_RZ_12and5kHz               0x01
#define FREQ_RZ_50kHZ                       0x02
#define FREQ_RZ_100kHZ                  0x03
#define FREQ_RZ_UNKNOWN                 0xFF

#define FORMAT_RZ_DOP                       0x00
#define FORMAT_RZ_OSN                       0x01

#define CTRL_PARR_PARITY                0x00
#define CTRL_PARR_ODDNESS               0x01

#define IDDEV_2RZTOUSB                  0x01

#define ENABLE_ADDR_REC                 0x01
#define DISABLE_ADDR_REC                0x00
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//#pragma pack(show)
#pragma pack(push,1)
//#pragma pack(show)

struct sInitDevice
{
    unsigned char ucFreqRZ;
    unsigned char ucFormatRZ;
    unsigned char ucCtrlParr;
    unsigned char ucAddrRecv;

    unsigned char pucMatrAddrRecv[SIZE_MATR_ADDR_RECV];
};

struct sInitDeviceEx
{
    struct sInitChannel
    {
        BYTE FreqRZ;
        BYTE FormatRZ;
        BYTE CtrlParr;
    } ParamChannel[MAX_COUNT_CHANNELS];

    BYTE AddrRecv;
    BYTE MatrAddrRecv[SIZE_MATR_ADDR_RECV];
};

struct sInfoDevice
{
    bool bCorrectInfo;      
    unsigned char   ucCodeErrorDevice;
    unsigned char   ucIDDevice;
    unsigned char   ucFreqRZ;
    unsigned char  ucCountChannels;
    unsigned short  usDensityRZ;
    unsigned short usPlantNum;
    unsigned short usNumPO;
    unsigned short usVersionPO;
};

struct sInfoDeviceEx
{
    bool bCorrectInfo;
    BYTE CodeErrorDevice;
    BYTE IDDevice;
    WORD NumPO;
    WORD VersionPO;
    WORD PlantNum;
    BYTE CountChannels;

    struct sInfoChannel
    {
        BYTE FreqRZ;
        WORD DensityRZ;
    } InfoChannel[MAX_COUNT_CHANNELS];
};

struct sRZStream
{
    unsigned char  CountRZMessage;
    unsigned short CountTrashRZMessage;
    unsigned short CountMissingRZMessage;
    bool IsMissingRZMessage;

    struct
    {
        unsigned char Address;
        unsigned char Low;
        unsigned char High;
        unsigned char Additional;
        unsigned char Channel;
    } RZ_DATA[MAX_COUNT_RZ_DATA];
    //Index RZ_DATA: [0 ... (CountRZMessage - 1)]
};

struct sRZStreamEx
{
    struct
    {
        union
        {
            struct
            {
                BYTE Low;
                BYTE High;
                BYTE Additional;    
                BYTE Address;                       
            };
            DWORD RzMessage;
        };
    } RZ_DATA[MAX_COUNT_RZ_DATA];

    struct 
    {
        BYTE Channel_0 : 4;
        BYTE Channel_1 : 4;
    } CHANNELS[MAX_COUNT_RZ_DATA / 2];

    BYTE System00;

    BYTE CountRZMessage;

    union
    {
        struct
        {   
            BYTE CountTrashRZMessageL;
            BYTE CountTrashRZMessageH;
        };
        WORD CountTrashRZMessage;
    };

    BYTE IsMissingRZMessage;

    union
    {
        struct
        {   
            BYTE CountMissingRZMessageL;
            BYTE CountMissingRZMessageH;
        };
        WORD CountMissingRZMessage;
    };

    BYTE System07;
    BYTE System08;
    BYTE System09;
    BYTE System10;
    BYTE System11;
    BYTE System12;
    BYTE System13;
    BYTE System14;
    BYTE System15;

    inline BYTE GetChannelRZMessage (int IndexRZMessage)
    {
        return (IndexRZMessage & 0x01) ? CHANNELS[IndexRZMessage >> 1].Channel_1 : CHANNELS[IndexRZMessage >> 1].Channel_0;
    }
};

struct sRZTimingData
{
    BYTE Data[MAX_COUNT_RZ_DATA];
};

#pragma pack(pop)
//#pragma pack(show)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_ConnectDevice (void);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_IsConnectToDevice (void);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_DisconnectDevice (void);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_InitDevice (sInitDevice*, sInfoDevice*);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_InitDeviceEx (sInitDeviceEx*, sInfoDeviceEx*);
CRZUSB_API void RzUsb_SetReadTimeout (unsigned long);
CRZUSB_API void RzUsb_SetWriteTimeout (unsigned long);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_RunReceiveRZ (void);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_StopReceiveRZ (void);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_ReceiveRZStream (sRZStream*);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_ReceiveRZStreamEx (sRZStreamEx*);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_IsReceiveRZStream (void);
//--------------------SUPPORT TIMING DATA------------------------------------
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_IsSupportTimingData (void);
CRZUSB_API bool RzUsb_GetTimingData (sRZTimingData*);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Как преобразовать структуры для с#?

Comment: Делаем простой маршалинг

Answer (score 0):

Это как бы смешивание управляемого и нативного кода. В данном случае в C# хорошо интегрируются COM объекты. Поэтому одним из способов интеграции является создание обвязки в виде COM объекта. В этом случае данные dll можно преобразовать в данные, понятные в управляемом коде.

Еще одним способом (мне нравится больше) является использование C++ CLR. Для этого создается проект типа Class Library и в нем CLR класс который будет управлять нативным dll. Здесь тоже придется данные преобразовывать, но это можно сделать в виде тех же CLR объектов.

Ниже я написал небольшой код для примера. Я в нем загружаю библиотеку работы с сокетом.

```
#pragma once

#include "windows.h"
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace System;

namespace NativeClasses {

public ref class AddrIn
{
public:
    int  Port;
    String^ sAddr;
};

public ref class NativeSocket 
{

u_short (*htons)(u_short);
unsigned long (*inet_addr)(const char*);

public:
    NativeSocket(void)
    {
        HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary (L"ws2_32.dll");
        if ( hm )
        {
            SOCKET (*socket)(int,int,int) = (SOCKET (*)(int,int,int)) GetProcAddress(hm, "socket"); 
            int (*closesocket)(SOCKET) = (int (*)(SOCKET)) GetProcAddress(hm, "socket"); 
            htons = (u_short (*)(u_short)) GetProcAddress(hm, "htons"); 
            inet_addr = (unsigned long (*)(const char*)) GetProcAddress(hm, "inet_addr"); 

            SOCKET s = (*socket) (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
            if (s)
                (*closesocket) (s);
            FreeLibrary(hm);
        }
    }

    void SetAddr( AddrIn^ Addr )
     {
         sockaddr_in addr = {0};
         addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
         addr.sin_port = (*htons)(Addr->Port);
         CString sAddr(Addr->sAddr); 
         CW2A asAddr(sAddr);
         addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = (*inet_addr)(asAddr);
     }    
};
}
```

Сборку с классами затем включается в ссылки проекта на C# и может использоваться обычным вызовом:

```
NativeClasses.NativeSocket s = new NativeClasses.NativeSocket();
NativeClasses.AddrIn addr = new NativeClasses.AddrIn() ;
addr.Port = 1000;
addr.sAddr = "10.1.0.100";
s.SetAddr(addr);
```

Для преобразования строк на мой взгляд удобнее всего использовать ATL. Остальное на усмотрение.